# Resharper intellisense isn't working with generated file

Tags: silverlight, resharper, wcf-ria-services

I used the feature provided in the RIA Services Toolkit to automatically generated a service client to a WCF service when you build the project.  The generated file is placed in ...\GeneratedWcfClientCode\ServiceReference.cs

The project compiles and runs successfully, however Resharper's intellisense isn't picking up that file and as a result is saying there are errors for the items defined in this file.

Is there anyway to force Resharper to recognize the generated file?

Comment: I have the same issue on Resharper 6.1.

Comment: I'm working on the same problem right now. The weird thing is, it works in some solutions and not in others. It works just fine in my new Silverlight 5 projects, but not on my old ones that I upgraded from Silverlight 4 to 5. Investigation continues....

Answer (score 0):

It appears it's because the client-side files generated by RIA aren't included as part of the Project.

I have just included the files from "Generated Code" in the solution and Reflector is happy once more. Not ideal, but should give you back your intellisense while the stars at JetBrains address this.

Answer (score 0):

I have only ReSharper 5.1.
This version has settings for generated code, see ReSharper->Options->Code Inspection->Generated Code.

[image]

There you can add all files and folders that must not be touched by ReSharper. Maybe your file/folder is in that list and so your file/folder is ignored by ReSharper's intellisence.